# The page-break-before property is not effective when generating HTML content for PDF documents

Tags: html, css

```
<table>some random content </table>

<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>

<div>some random content </div>
```

Hello everyone,

I'm currently using the code snippet above in an attempt to separate my table and the div element onto two separate pages when generating a PDF. However, it appears that   is not functioning as expected, and both the table and the div remain on the same page. I've also experimented with the CSS style and  , but encountered the same issue.

Tried Solution:

1. `<div style="break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>`
2. `<div style="break-before:page">&nbsp;</div>`
3. `<div style="page-break-before:page">&nbsp;</div>`
4. `<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>`
5. CSS Style

I would appreciate any insights into the potential issues or solutions for achieving the desired page separation. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't `break-before: page;` what you're after? ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before))

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post, I have tried 'break-before: page;', but it is not working as well

Comment: When you say "generating a PDF", are you using the browser print functionality to produce that PDF, or some other approach?

Comment: Hmm, it appears to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/623jo5mL/

Answer (score 0):

The page-break-before CSS property doesn't work on  elements or most block-level elements when it comes to generating PDFs. It's primarily intended for controlling page breaks when printing web pages, and its behavior can be inconsistent when it comes to PDF generation.

If you want to ensure that your table and the following  appear on separate pages in a PDF, you can use a different approach. One commonly used method is to wrap each section in a  with a specific class and then apply a CSS rule to force page breaks before those classes. Here's an example:

```
<div class="page-break"> <!-- Page 1 content: your table -->
  <table>
    <!-- table content -->
  </table>
</div>

<div class="page-break"> <!-- Page 2 content: your <div> -->
  <div>
    <!-- div content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.page-break {
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: So Print > Export PDF does not just turn whatever would be printed into exactly the same PDF? Because in my experience it does...

Answer (score 0):

The `page-break-before` CSS property may not be supported by all browsers or PDF viewers. It is  important to note that the behavior of page breaks can vary across different rendering engines and environments. You can try using different ways like adjusting margins, using `page-break-inside`, or using a different method for generating PDFs to achieve the desired page break behavior.

Comment: That property has [pretty much global support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_page-break-before) (with the exception of some mobile browsers from ~10 years ago), it's unlikely this is a browser support issue.

Comment: yeah you are right but you can never be to sure he didn't specify the browser he was using